# <virtualport type='openvswitch'/> is NOT recognized

Tags: libvirt

In order to make my vm use the openvswitch interface I have to add the following lines to a vm xml config file:

I edit the file, anyway while the first line is corrctly saved, the second one is not. It simply disappears, so I think the virtualport tag is not recognized...but this leads to an error when I start the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it requires libvirt 0.10.0+ to use `<virtualport type='openvswitch'/>`. check your libvirt version first.